# Getting error "A MessageReceived handler is blocking the gateway task." In Spambot Discord C#

Tags: c#, discord.net

In this command, I want the user to input an integer, and then the string he/she wants to spam. After it asks for the string, I get an error in the CMD saying "A MessageReceived handler is blocking the gateway task."

For example the user could say

*!spamstring 29*

then

*Get on CSGO!*

The bot will spam *Get on CSGO!* 29 times. Here's the code:

```
[Command("spamstring")]
public async Task spamstring([Remainder] int times)
{
    var user = Context.Client.GetUser(Context.User.Id);
    if (times > 68)
    {
        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("*YOU CANNOT GO OVER 69* :eggplant: ");
    }
    else
    {
        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("You chose to spam " + times + " times, what do you want to spam?");
        string message = Console.ReadLine();
        if (message.Contains("@everyone"))
        {
            await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Do not mention everyone!");
        }
        else
        {
            await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(":fire: *SPAMMING* :fire: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
            {
                await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(message);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept the fundamentals but when trying to debug his code, this particular command broke everything so I just rewrote it. I started off by changing how he took in the "message" in the **public task**. He tries using a string called later in the function which wouldn't work and trying to read the console. This wouldn't work because Discord won't log anything until it's recognized as a command so I changed that to a parameter. From there it's simple, instead of using **Context,Channel.SendMessageAsync** I simply did **ReplyAsync**. I also added an Alias. Also instead of using **message.Contains()** which wouldn't work, I used an if statement with if (messageToString() == "@everyone").

```
[Command("spamstring")]
    [Alias("sp", "spamming", "juanspam")]
    public async Task spamming(int times, string message)
    {
        //try and refrain from BIG if statements like this
        if (times > 68)
        {
            await Context.Message.DeleteAsync();
            await ReplyAsync(Context.User.Mention + " *YOU CANNOT GO OVER 69* :eggplant:");
        }
        else
        {
            await Context.Message.DeleteAsync();
            await ReplyAsync("You chose to spam " + times + " times, what do you want to spam?");


            //NEW IF
            if (message.ToString() == "@everyone")
            {
                await ReplyAsync("Don't do that bitch. You deserve to be spammed for that!");
            }
            else
            {
                await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(":fire: *SPAMMING* :fire: ");

                //spam loop
                for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
                {
                    await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(message);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
                }
            }


        }
       //END BIG OF
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What did you change? What does this code do? Explain code, don't just spoonfeed.

Comment: Sorry this was just my friends post but I'll explain: - Look above ^